# What is difference between node-fetch(nodejs) and requests(python)

Tags: python-requests, node-fetch

python codes get response but javascript code can't get response.
what is diff between the two??

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const url = "http://host3.dreamhack.games:15592/img_viewer"
const imageUrl = "/static/dream.png"
const data = {
    "url": imageUrl
}
const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
const text = await res.text()
console.log(text)

//<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
//<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
//<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
//<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the //server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

```py
import requests

url = "http://host3.dreamhack.games:15592/img_viewer"
imageUrl = "/static/dream.png"
data = {
    "url": imageUrl
}
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

I think the two codes are same, why get different response?
(after time above url is not available)

** server

```py
@app.route("/img_viewer", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def img_viewer():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("img_viewer.html")
    elif request.method == "POST":
        url = request.form.get("url", "")
        urlp = urlparse(url)
        if url[0] == "/":
            url = "http://localhost:8000" + url
        elif ("localhost" in urlp.netloc) or ("127.0.0.1" in urlp.netloc):
            data = open("error.png", "rb").read()
            img = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf8")
            return render_template("img_viewer.html", img=img)
        try:
            data = requests.get(url, timeout=3).content
            img = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf8")
        except:
            data = open("error.png", "rb").read()
            img = base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf8")
        return render_template("img_viewer.html", img=img)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 reasons:

1. The headers in `node-js` might be drifferent by default. You could specify them to make the requests identical tho.
2. It seems like `javascript` has a different **fingerprint** than `python-requests`, even when using the same headers. Some websites like cloudfare can detect that, and then usually throw a `403 [Forbidden]` http error.
   But I didn't find out, what exactly is defferent that case.